# To-Do lists rendered differently on GitHub pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

The README.md on github is rendered as:

[image]

While on github pages it is being rendered as:

[image]

Notice the unordered list like formatting which I don't want. I have tried using GitHub Flavored Markdown by editing `_config.yml`:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-cayman
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

But that doesn't fix anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The difference here lies in the theme (and therefore CSS directives).

GitHub primarily uses a variant of `jekyll-theme-primer`. Your site however uses `jekyll-theme-cayman`.

If you do want to continue using the Cayman theme, you can simply add some custom CSS styling to your page's layout to emulate the rendering from `jekyll-theme-primer`.

Comment: So if I change the theme to `jekyll-theme-primer` in `_config.yml` will it fix the task list rendering?